# 50$ fee on transfer from bitcoin core to electrum

Tags: wallet, electrum

Yesterday i've tried to transfer the minimum amount of btc [ 0.00001 BTC ] from my bitcoin core wallet to the electrum one. The problem is that only 0.00000504 BTC were sent to the electrum wallet and !!!0.00109000 BTC!!! were sent to some random address.

I am curious why this happened.

ps: The blockchain explorer says it is all in one transaction, but sent to two different addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to buy something that costs $1 and all you have is a $10 bill. Your transaction will take the $10 bill and out of it $1 will go one way and $9 will go another way. This is called "change".

You didn't have an available output of precisely the amount needed. So the wallet consumed the best available output it could, send the amount you requested to the destination you requested, paid a transaction fee, and returned the rest as "change" to another of your addresses.

Comment: Correct. After rescanning the wallet for 2 hours I saw all the money. That is very interesting.
Thanks David.